# How do you access "app"  (ref. to session) on via heroku console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

When working on localhost you can access **app** (*ActionDispatch::Integration::Session*) to test your app? (e.g. test controller)

When using heroku console I am not able to see **app** var, does anybody know the way?

Bamboo stack on Heroku, Rails version 3.0.3

Comment: Which stack are you running and which version of rails? I can access "app" on cedar/rails 3.2.6.

Comment: Thanks, it is bamboo stack and rails version 3.0.3. Also edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Heroku console, you don't have the app object when running rails console. The commands go through Heroku's "routing mesh", so I believe that's why you don't have full access.

Instead, you have access to your models and application logic.

Comment: This is heroku specific? Since as mentioned in question I do have session when testing locally via console.

Comment: I can confirm that heroku console doesn't give access to App. Going to edit my answer.